# converting numerical output labels to categorical vectors in keras

Tags: python, vector, keras, deep-learning, categorical-data

I'm creating a Deep learning multi-classification model in Keras and I have converted my outputlabel training set y_train from numerical values ranging from 1 to 14 to output vectors looking like this `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] => representing the number 2` . This is the code I used in python (keras):

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

However, because it converts these outputlabels into a vector of length 15 instead of 14 because it adds zero as a potential output as well. My original numpy array y_train looked like this: `[1,8,9,7,2,2,8...]` and it should be converted to a vector of length 14 instead of 15 to avoid extra loss when training the model. Is there a simpel way to avoid using zero as a potential output class?

(`num_classes = 14`  as a parameter of to_categorical gives an error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your labels are from 1 to 14, try this simple trick:

```
y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(y_train)-1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you